Justification for power expansion of a constant
In non-degenerate time-independent perturbation theory, it is common to express the perturbed energy eigenvalues as
$$E=E^{(0)}+\lambda E^{(1)}+\lambda^2E^{(2)}+...\tag1$$
And the eigenstate as
$$\vert n\rangle=\vert n^{(0)}\rangle+\lambda\vert n^{(1)}\rangle+\lambda^2\vert n^{(2)}\rangle+...\tag2$$
Where superscript denotes order and $\lambda$ is a parameter that is set to $1$ later on.
Now the above expressions must solve
$$(H_0+\lambda H')\ \vert n\rangle=E\ \vert n\rangle\tag3$$
Substituting $(1)$ and $(2)$ in $(3)$ and equating the coefficients of same powers of $\lambda$ we get our answer.
But how to justify this equating? Should we treat the lambda in these equations as a genuine variable until the very last, for which we know how to justify it?

This can all be found in Kato, Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators.  Under appropriate conditions
(notably if $H_0$ and $H_1$ are bounded linear operators on a Banach space and $E^{(0)}$ is an isolated point of the spectrum of $H_0$ which is a simple eigenvalue), there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that the eigenvalue $E(\lambda)$ of $H_0 + \lambda H_1$ and the one-dimensional projection on the corresponding eigenvector $\vert n \rangle$
are analytic functions of $\lambda$ for $|\lambda| < \epsilon$.  Thus they are
represented by series in powers of $\lambda$ converging for $|\lambda| < \epsilon$.
The series may or may not converge at $\lambda = 1$.
